# Help copy large file from iPhone to PC

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I’m coding the Record application. However, I have problem with copying the file from iPhone device to the PC after recording. I used Attach File function on Email but it doesn’t allow with large size > 10MB file. I haven’t found any solution yet for this problem. iTune 9.0 has “Include Voice Memos” function, can i do the same with my application ? “Include My App” e.g.
Anybody knows other solution for this problem? 
Thanks for read

Answer (score 1):

In my apps, I use [CocoaHTTPServer](http://code.google.com/p/cocoahttpserver/) to get local info into and off of the phone. You run the server and out-of-the-box, it indexes all the files in the documents directory for you to download from any browser on the same wifi network.  Give it a shot as it is a easy to implement solution for getting large files off the phone without having to resort to something clunky like email

Comment: this assumes that the device and computer are on the same wifi network, which may not always be pratical

Comment: It is also not practical to send a 10MB file over edge or 3g.

Answer (score -1):

You really only have a couple non-optimal options here:

1. Email the audio file, which has a file size limitation (as noted in your question)
2. Upload the audio file to a server and then give users the ability to download the file on their computers (this might be somewhat optimal if the user is on a WIFI/3G network, but is less than optimal if the user is on an EDGE network)

FYI: There is no way to transfer the file through iTunes.

Comment: It is innacurate as it implies there are only 2 ways to do this